# How to reverse a Hard HEAD reset in Android Studio

Tags: android, github

I did a Hard HEAD reset in Android Studio, and I lost a good chunk of my work. I have no idea how to reverse the reset. I'm in Ubuntu, and I've tried using `git` commands via the console to no avail. Basically I have no clue what I just did, or how to reverse my actions, except that I've reset my project to the very first commit I ever made, and if I don't recover the newer commits, GitHub will delete them permanently in the next few days or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio bases on IntelliJ IDEA, so you can try using *Local history* feature:

[Using Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-local-history.html)

[Restoring a File from Local History - JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/restoring-a-file-from-local-history.html)

Comment: I've already tried this, nothing changes. The class files are still the same old class file from the initial commit I made.

Comment: Oh my god it worked, I had to first click on the the folder I wanted to revert, and THEN click on history... you are a god send thank you. I am such an idiot.

Comment: You could try achieve the same using many `git` commands, browsing through logs, hoping that `git` won't garbage collect your changes... But using this feature is faster :)

Comment: @the_prole You've learnt your lesson now about hard resetting, haven't you young man?

Comment: @Ascorbin Never again.

Comment: @the_prole I usually make a 'backup branch' before hard resetting and keep it around a while, in case I change my mind ;)